# SendMail() from .NET custom html combined with templateId

Tags: visualforce, soap-api, email-template, c#, .net

Is there any way to use sendMail() via SOAP API but combine using VisualForce template within Salesforce and passing additional an object to it or additional html from my .NET app.

At present I'm having to use RazorEngine in my C# to parse a full html template using my own .NET models then set the htmlBody property of my SingleMailMessage before calling sendMail().

I'm also using targetObjectId setting it with the SF userId.

Comment: Have you tried specifying the [`templateId`](http://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_sendemail.htm#BaseEmailTitle) as the Visualforce template Id?

Comment: Yes tried that. If you set templateId and also set htmlBody on a SingleMailMessage object the email will just contain your htmlBody as the entire content bypassing using the template.